# Разрешения для папки сессий

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, access

Я использую PHP на nginx. Какие права должны быть установлена для папки сессий? Сейчас права 777 - это позволяет создавать и записывать сессии, но мне кажется это не лучшая практика. Должен ли я указать права 755 для www-data или мне нужен как то по другому настроить эту папку, что бы не иметь проблем с безопасностью?

Comment: Как именно вы используете php на nginx и где у вас прописаны настройки для использования этотй папки сессий?

Comment: Я использую Codeigniter. Мой скрипт создает файл сессии после логина и сохраняет внутри папки /var/www/html/session

Comment: Как именно Codeigniter связан с nginx, кем как запускается, где прописан пользователь от имени которого это всё запускается?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно чтобы процесс PHP мог писать в эту директорию. 
0777 - будет работать всегда.

Допустим что PHP работает из под юзера www-data и из под группы www-data.

Если владельцем директории для сессий является этот же www-data, то вам достаточно 0755 прав на директорию (то есть только чтобы владелец мог туда писать).

Если группа владельца директории www-data, а юзер какой-то другой, то надо 0775 - чтобы и  группа могла писать в эту директорию.